# Student attempting to replicating underscore's extend function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi I'm trying to create based off of underscore an extend function.  I have no clue how to do this.  I've had success creating other replicas of other underscore properties but this one is just not bringing up any ideas to mind.  I'm hoping someone can explain how to create ._extend using native javascript and how it works as well.  Here is the starting frame.  Thanks in advanced.

```
var extend = function(obj){


}
```

Comment: Surely if you have replicated other methods you could read the source code and come up with more specific question than this as well as have *some* idea how it works. This question is far too broad for this site as it currently stands

Comment: Underscore's source code - and thus the implementation of `extend` - is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js). See line 1061 for the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

[Underscore extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) method basically accepts two parameters which are `destination` and `sources`, and return the `destination` object. To replicate its functionality, a simple [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) would do.

**E.g.**

```
var extendObject = function (destination, ...sources) {
  return Object.assign(destination, ...sources);
}
```

If you notice, the method above uses [Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), which is only supported by ES >= 2015. If you want to support for the lower version of ES, you can simply do,

```
var extendObject = function (destination, source) {
  return Object.assign(destination, source);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var dest = {a: 1, b: 2};
var src1 = {c: 3, d: 4};
var src2 = {e: 5, f: 6};

// ES >= 2015
extendObject(dest, src1); //{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
extendObject(dest, src1, src2); //{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}

// ES <= 5
extendObject(dest, src1); //{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
extendObject(dest, src2); //{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(myObj) gives you an array containing all keys (attribute names) in you object. Then it's just a matter of iterating over this array and cloning the value of the source object into the destination object based on the key names. You can clone an objects key like this:

```
dest['someAttr'] = origin['someAttr'];
```

Suppose the value of origin.someAttr is 5. After doing the above your "dest" object should also have an dest.someAttr with the value 5.